# Can't export point clouds as a ply file

Tags: export, point-clouds

I want to export vertices (no mesh exists) as ply file. However, after exporting the data by File->Export->.ply, the generated ply file contains no vertices. Can anyone help? I'm using blender 2.8.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've [submitted a patch](https://developer.blender.org/D2947) to address that (allows to export *loose geometry*)  2 years ago. Unfortunately I don't have the time porting the patch to Blender 2.8x right now. However, it should still work for the latest and greatest 2.7x...

Comment: Just updated the patch for 2.8x :)

Answer (score 1):

Your assessment is accurate, Blender's ply exporter loops over the triangles. This can be seen in line 90 of [export_ply.py](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/io_mesh_ply/export_ply.py).

```
for i, f in enumerate(mesh.loop_triangles):
```

Any vertex that is not part of a face isn't included in the exported mesh in Blender 2.8.